# Script not found index.html angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Aerosmith Messenger</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/spinner.css" />

  <!--<script src="src/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <am-root>
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
      <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
    </div>
  </am-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to include jquery script. And it does not work when i include it like this (commented line). Help me resolve this issue because i need to include some other scripts.
By "does not work" i mean all the time that commented script is not found in console of a browser.

Comment: where is your jquery-1.6.4.js file in your directory? and where is your index.html located?

Comment: index.html in src, jquery - src/scripts

Comment: so you should include your jquery library like: <script src="./scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script> or <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

Comment: GET http://localhost:4200/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js (not found)

Comment: if you go to localhost:4200/src/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js in your browser it finds the file?

Comment: it redirects me to localhost:4200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148016/discussion-between-jv-lobo-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of angular-cli(angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3) provides an assets folder under src directory. You just need to add src property of an image tag as below,

```
   <img src="./assets/logo.png">
```

But as turns out i ditn't need to include any scripts to my index.html. The main problem was that sometimes my project didn't detect the changes. I mean - in past i added line to include jquery on index.html, my project didn't detect it and therefore browser didn't show any errors (not found) and after that all the time i thoutht that i was working with jquery because of that included jquery on index.html. But actually jquery was working because i also included it in different way. So be careful about it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you provide the path of "jquery-1.6.4.js" exactly where it is located. Check the src/scripts. 
And if it is there then you should include it somewhat like this,
"~/src/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js".
Assuming you have "src" folder in which "script" folder exists, which has your jquery file.

Comment: in which folder you have the jquery file/

Comment: [project name]/src/scripts

Comment: so try including it like "~/src/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"

Comment: still not found

Comment: try to put the js file in the root of your project directory. I mean projectName/jquery-1.6.4.js and then see if it finds it.

Comment: can't find there either (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148019/discussion-between-amit-mishra-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Try add script and style to `angular-cli.json` in root project, as follows:

```
"apps": [{
    ...
    ... 
    "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "./styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "assets/js/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "assets/js/custom.js"
    ],
```

Comment: i've already tried it - still not found 
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
],

Comment: Check `angular-cli.json` file Carefully. First, make sure you install the modules by angular-cli

Comment: Unfortunately none of these answers solved my problem